# Splitting a list of links into a list of domains

Tags: python, list, url, urlparse

so I have multiple lists that contain links of websites:

```
['www.google.com', 'www.yahoo.com', 'www.amazon.com']
```

And I want to obtain a list as follows:

```
['google', 'yahoo', 'amazon']
```

How can I use urllib to retrieve this? I got the following:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
domain = urlparse('http://www.google.com').netloc
print(domain)
```

But I do not how to do it for a list and this gives as result [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) instead of just google.

Comment: What's the purpose of the list? You're stripping away a lot of information by reducing it down to just, for example, `amazon`. Should `amazon.co.uk` and `amazon.net` be considered the same thing? Should `google.com` and `mail.google.com` be considered the same?

Comment: I am going to combine the lists to create a hyperlink. So I only need the name of the website on which you can click in order to go to the website.

Comment: If not bound to use urllib, then alternatively you can use regex or simple string split will also do just fine with it.(regex would be overkill in this case)

Answer (score 1):

If you have just normal links like you provided then just doing this will work for you.

```py
links=['www.google.com', 'www.yahoo.com', 'www.amazon.com']
print([link.split(".")[1] for link in links])
# ["google","yahoo","amazon"]
```

But if `link` have multiple sub-domain then it won't work as expected.

I have found library will do your work as expected, [tldextract](https://pypi.org/project/tldextract/):

```
links=['https://www.google.com/asdfl', 'translate.google.com', 'afe.amdfad.azon.com']
import tldextract

print([tldextract.extract(link).domain for link in links])
# ['google', 'google', 'azon']
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below should work.

```
import re
domains = ['www.google.com', 'www.yahoo.com', 'www.amazon.com']
result = [re.findall(r'www\.(.*)\.\w{2,5}', domain)[0] for domain in domains]
```

Result:

```
['google', 'yahoo', 'amazon']
```

Comment: What about `google.com` or `translate.google.com`?

Comment: Well, it would return transalate.google if the URL is in the format that the author provided (www.translate.google.com).

Comment: There is no such website like `www.translate.google.com`!

Comment: In that case this would work: result = [re.findall(r'\w*\.(.*)\.\w{2,5}', domain)[0] for domain in domains]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest giving the entire netloc to the user, makes things a lot easier to understand. But, for your problem, if the data is consistent, you could also simply use `split`.

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

domain = urlparse('http://www.google.com').netloc
print(domain.split('.')[1])
```

This method does have its downsides with subdomains though:
translate.google.com -> google (which I think would be wrong)